# get attribute value of different nodes from xml using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file with data as follows

```
   <P1 type="CP" name="E01+W">
    <DNo>4423</DNo>
    <CNo>abc</CNo>
  </P1>

    <P2 type="DP" name="E02+W">
    <DNo>5623</DNo>
    <CNo>xyz</CNo>
  </P2>
```

How to I get Attribute value type="CP" and "DP" of P1 and P2 node in one column.
More like Traverse to each node of  and its sub node and get each subnode type attribute value in one column.

```
Type   Name
CP     EO1
DP     EO2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx)

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse([string]);
xml.Elements().Select( x => new { Type = x.Attribute("type").Value, 
                                  Name =  .Attribute("Name").Value});
```